# How to find midpoint or centroid of a route from a list of lat lons without Google API?

Tags: android, latitude-longitude, centroid

I have a route charted in my application that joins 4 lat long points. I am saving the latlong values in a list.
[image]

Can you guide me as to how to find the centeroid ...or midpoint lat/lon of this route.

Comment: As midpoint you mean the point at "half the route" or the center point of the 4 lat longs.

Comment: Center point of the 4 latlongs so that i can set that lat lon value as the center using a method like setCenter(calculatedLat,calculatedLon,zoomValue)

Answer (score 0):

Here you go:
https://github.com/grundid/osm-tools/blob/master/osm-tools-api/src/main/java/org/osmtools/utils/Centroid.java

Just pass your points to this class and it will calculate centroid.

Comment: Thats great Mubix! I am trying it out will let you know the result. :)

Comment: Mubix, the Geopoint in your example, do they contain latitude and longitudes? is there a way to obtain the centroid just using the latitude and longitude values as double values?

Comment: What is the center of 53 and 57? If you can calculate that then what is the center of 4 and 9? Done? You are ready!

Comment: You will need to pass the lat long as instances of GeoPoint .. you can find the GeoPoint class here: https://gitorious.org/android-maps-api/android-maps-api/source/d298d56bfc2c2cc10ddcdc880485931d4439266b:src/com/google/android/maps/GeoPoint.java#L49